# For hololens, using MixedRealityToolKit V2 for unity. How to access spatial awareness to get surfacetypes (wall, floor, ceiling etc)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

MRTK v2 Documentation about the subsystem in spatialawarness which separates the walls and floors are vague. Older versions of the toolkit(holotoolkit) had at least example to understand more about surface types. Please help understand about querying and enumeration with respect to walls/floors from spatial data.

I am working on a simple project and I want to put a material only on the walls. Spacial awareness systems helps giving wireframe or occulution to entire mapped mesh (layer 31- Spatial Awareness). Is there a way to have walls alone in a different layer? for organisation. Thank you.

Setup
Unity Version [2019.1.7f1]
MRTK Version [v2.0]
Target Platform
HoloLens
HoloLens 2

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness.SpatialAwarenessSurfaceTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SpatialAwarenessSurfaceTypes is not used elsewhere in MRTKv2, but instead you can use the Scene Understanding SDK. SceneObject of Scene Understanding SDK can represents  an instance of a "thing" e.g. a wall, a floor, a ceiling, etc..

More information please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/scene-understanding-sdk#sceneobjects